# PWA Local storage is cleared after latest iOS update

Tags: ios, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that uses local storage to store the users JWT. This JWT is used for making authenticated requests to an API.

I've have some users that have reported that once they update their device to the latest version of iOS they have been logged out (token expiry is set quite long so it definitely didn't expire).

I've tested this on a few devices before and after the latest update and it seems to be consistent, but I'm not sure if this expected behaviour.

This seems to be specifically when the PWA has been installed on the device, rather than in the browser.

I would expect that local storage shouldn't be getting cleared as it works just the same as in the browser.

Is this expected behaviour in iOS or am i missing something?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited, "Is this expected behaviour in iOS or am i missing something?"